# tailwind list items dropping a line

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have the following HTML in my application,

```
<div class="col-span-1 h-40 border-gray-400 border bg-white">
                    <div class="border-b border-gray-400 py-6 pl-4">
                        <h3 class="text-xl font-brand font-bold text-gray-800 text-l">Your Teams</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-full border-b border-gray-400 flex p-5 last:border-b-0 items-center">
                        <p class="text-gray-800 text-xl">Team 1</p>
                        <ul class="ml-auto">
                            <li class="border-2 border-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block">
                                <router-link to="" class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
                                    <img src="../assets/avatar.png" class="rounded-full"/>
                                </router-link>
                            </li>
                            <li class="border-2 border-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block -ml-3">
                                <router-link to="" class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
                                    <img src="../assets/avatar.png" class="rounded-full"/>
                                </router-link>
                            </li>
                            <li class="border-2 border-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block -ml-3">
                                <router-link to="" class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
                                    <img src="../assets/avatar.png" class="rounded-full"/>
                                </router-link>
                            </li>
                            <li class="border-2 border-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block -ml-3">
                                <router-link to="" class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
                                    <img src="../assets/avatar.png" class="rounded-full"/>
                                </router-link>
                            </li>
                            <li class="border-blue-400 bg-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block -ml-3">
                                <router-link to="" class="text-m rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden text-white">
                                    +5
                                </router-link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This should produce something similar to this,

[image]

However what I am getting is,

[image]

I cannot understand why the final list item is dropping as if it has a top margin?

Comment: How about a link to the working code?

Comment: look intro ether using `float: left` or `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: Maybe it's related to the size of the image vs the sizes off the text... Drop the +5 element and see if it's just that it's the last item in the list or maybe the size of the underlying image element pushes all the image elements higher?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the avatars and the count circle in line by just adding a `flex` and `items-center` to your `ul`:

```html
<div class="col-span-1 h-40 border-gray-400 border bg-white">
    <div class="border-b border-gray-400 py-6 pl-4">
        <h3 class="text-xl font-brand font-bold text-gray-800 text-l">Your Teams</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full border-b border-gray-400 flex p-5 last:border-b-0 items-center">
        <p class="text-gray-800 text-xl">Team 1</p>
        <ul class="ml-auto flex items-center">
            <li class="border-2 border-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block">
                <router-link to="" class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
                    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/50" class="rounded-full"/>
                </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="border-2 border-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block -ml-3">
                <router-link to="" class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
                    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/50" class="rounded-full"/>
                </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="border-2 border-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block -ml-3">
                <router-link to="" class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
                    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/50" class="rounded-full"/>
                </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="border-2 border-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block -ml-3">
                <router-link to="" class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
                    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/50" class="rounded-full"/>
                </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="border-blue-400 bg-blue-400 rounded-full inline-block -ml-3">
                <router-link to="" class="text-m rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden text-white">
                    +5
                </router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [live demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/FA9JCns2ko).